# Ionic Custom colors - SASS

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, gulp-sass

I am a newbie for Ionic and sass framework.

I am trying add custom colors for my app so i am trying to update      `ionic.app.scss` file located inside scss folder.

So , if i try to override an existing variable say :

`$assertive : #F35C6 !default;`

it works fine but if i create a custom color say :

`$my-custom-color : #F35C6F !default;`

It doesn't work .
Am i doing it correctly , Please Help!

Thanks.

EDIT :

ionic.app.scss file :

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/*
To customize the look and feel of Ionic, you can override the variables
in ionic's _variables.scss file.

For example, you might change some of the default colors:

$light:                           #fff !default;
$stable:                          #f8f8f8 !default;
$positive:                        #387ef5 !default;
$calm:                            #11c1f3 !default;
$balanced:                        #33cd5f !default;
$energized:                       #ffc900 !default;
$assertive:                       #ef473a !default;
$royal:                           #886aea !default;
$dark:                            #444 !default;


*/

$my-custom-color : #F35C6F !default;
// The path for our ionicons font files, relative to the built CSS in www/css
$ionicons-font-path: "../lib/ionic/fonts" !default;

// Include all of Ionic
@import "../www/lib/ionic/scss/ionic";
```

Usage :

```
<label class="item item-input">
  <i class="icon ion-at placeholder-icon my-custom-color"></i>
  <input type="email" placeholder="Email ID">
</label>
```

Comment: Provide the code where you declare it (with the other variables) and also where you use it.

Comment: @theblindprophet : I have edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add custom color variables, that's all it does, it creates a variable. The Ionic colors on the other hand, all have several CSS classes in the Ionic CSS file that takes care of allowing you to use `.positive` in your view for example.

Here is the CSS for the `$positive` color from the Ionic source files:

```
.positive, a.positive {
  color: $positive;
}
.positive-bg {
  background-color: $positive;
}
.positive-border {
  border-color: $button-positive-border;
}
```

These classes are not created for your own color, by adding these to your own CSS, you can achieve the same behavior.

Comment: Thanks @Dexter , So what should i do if i want to create my own custom colors tied to  custom variables.

Comment: Just copy what I have posted, create a variable like so: `$custom-color` and replace `positive` with `custom-color` in my example and should be good to go.

Comment: What I see here is a variable `$positive:                        #387ef5 !default;` 
 inside _variable.scss inside ionic library. this in turn create a css (ionic.css)

    `.positive, a.positive {
  color: #387ef5; }

.positive-bg {
  background-color: #387ef5; }

.positive-border {
  border-color: #0c60ee; }`

can't we achive something like this for `$custom-color`

Comment: Not automatically as far as I know, they are all predefined in that file. There is no mixin in any of the files to generate those classes.

Comment: SASS does that i think .may be you can get an idea with http://robferguson.org/2015/07/07/customising-ionic-with-sass this.